# Output from a naive sort of list Prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog, output

I am to implement a roster management system in Prolog. I run into an issue with my sort, namely I can't figure out if it's actually sorting or not because no output occurs! Here is my process to call naive_sort and show_records:

```
process(3, Roster) :-
  nl,
  naive_sort(Roster, Sorted),
  show_records(Sorted),
  nl, nl, menu(Roster).
```

And here is my naive_sort:

```
naive_sort(List,Sorted):-perm(List,Sorted),is_sorted(Sorted).

is_sorted([]).
is_sorted([_]).
is_sorted([X,Y|T]):-X=<Y,is_sorted([Y|T]).

perm([], []).
perm([X | Y], Z) :- perm(Y, W), remove_list(X, Z, W).
```

My remove_list works perfectly fine, I can easily remove any student by their name or ID. So I don't believe there is any issue with that. Here is my show_records:

```
show_records(Roster) :-
   Roster = [ID | Name],
   write('\tID = '),
   ID = [Grade | D],
   write(Grade),
   write('\tName = '),
   D = [E | F],
   format("~s", [E]),
   write('\tGrade = '),
   F = [G | _],
   write(G),
nl,
show_records(Name).
```

show_records also works fine, so I am positive the issue is either with my naive_sort (which I can't seem to find out to see if it works because I get no output) or the issue is with my calling of the show_records after I call naive_sort. Here is a sample of what happens when I enter "choice 3" to output Roster sorted by ID:

```
    Class Roster management system
    ==============================
       MENU
    ==============================
    0. Reset Roster
    1. Load Roster from file
    2. Store Roster to file
    3. Display Roster sorted by ID
    4. Add student to Roster
    5. Remove student from Roster
    6. Exit
    Enter your choice (followed by ID '.'): 3.

    Class Roster management system
    ==============================
       MENU
    ==============================
```

If you can offer any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong here I'd really appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, I pretty much only had to change my is_sorted to handle lists. Here is my working code.

```
naive_sort(Roster,Sorted):-perm(Roster,Sorted),is_sorted(Sorted).

is_sorted([]).
is_sorted([_]).
is_sorted([ [X | XT], [Y | YT] | T]) :- X < Y, is_sorted([ [Y | YT] | T]).

takeout(Item, [Item | L], L).
takeout(Item, [X | L], [X | L1]) :- takeout(Item, L, L1).

perm([], []).
perm([X | Y], Z) :- perm(Y, W), takeout(X, Z, W).
```